# Why can I add a decimal number in int datatype to a string without a datatype conversion

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

I am a new programmer trying to understand why this Java code works. I am not in a class and this is not homework.

The exercise asked for user input of a decimal number and for the program to convert that number to decimal. Following an example of a slightly different program in the textbook, this is the code I wrote. It works, but I don't understand why.

```
while (decimalNumber != 0) {

     binaryNumber = decimalNumber % 2 + binaryNumber;
     decimalNumber = decimalNumber / 2;

  }
  System.out.println("The decimal number " + decimalNumber +
     " in binary is: " + binaryNumber);
```

The variable `binaryNumber` is of type `String` and the variable `decimalNumber` is of type `int`. Why can I add an `int` to a `String` without some kind of explicit/formal conversion?

This is my very first question here, so please excuse any faux pas committed!

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit conversion performed. This happens to be a special case of how the `+` operator is defined in the [Java Language Specification, §15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +
>
> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.
>
> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.
>
> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.28).

Of course, a Java compiler/runtime may optimize this in any way that makes the end result the same (e.g. using StringBuilders for multiple concatenations, or converting+concatenating in the same step to avoid creating short-lived String instances)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize the conversion was implicit. I spent too much time on previous exercise with errors involving mismatched types that I was wary of putting two different datatypes in the same line of code without doing something to match them.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that an `int` can *always* be represented as a `String` and you're performing a `String` concatenation with the `+` operator, the compiler implicitly casts this for you hence the need for an explicit cast is not a necessity.

thus the code:

```
binaryNumber = decimalNumber % 2 + binaryNumber;
```

Would first evaluate `decimalNumber % 2` and then the compiler will convert the result to a `String` prior to concatenating it with `binaryNumber`.

Comment: This actually isn't widening, since `String s = 3` isn't a valid assignment. This only happens when the concatenation operator is used, and has a special case in the language spec.

Comment: It's still necessary to mention that this is a consequence of there being concatenation. Stating that it's casted before concatenation doesn't show that the cast (or rather, conversion) is a consequence of it being a non-String operand of the concatenation operator.

Comment: @hexafraction sure, hope the edit makes it more clear.